# How to create a loop from Excel worksheet names?

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

A very basic question here from a new python user.

I have an Excel sheet with 3 tabs

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# Load in the workbook and assign wb as name
wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
# Get sheet names
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

Which gives these 3 in this example:

```
['Sheet1', 'Fuel', 'Games']
```

So my question is how do I make these into a loop list (not sure why I'd want to other than I cannot figure out how to!)

Comment: You mean how to iterate the list (`for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames`)?

Comment: You probably want to access the worksheets? `for ws in wb:…`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# Load in the workbook and assign wb as name
wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
# Get sheet names
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    print(sheet_name)
```

Comment: Great thanks, and how do I then select each name as a variable?